# Event listener of removefeature does not get executed when a feature is removed from the vectorsource

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer

As shown in the below posted code, I want to execute some side effects in `evtListener` when a feature is removed from the vector source.
At run time, when `deleteSelectedGeometry` function is invoked, the geometry gets deleted, but the event-listener `evtListener` posted below in the code is never invoked, hence, the
side effect code in it cannot be executed.

To solve this issue, I registered for the event `clear` of the vector source, when I do clear the vector source, the listener registered to listen to the event `clear` gets executed.

Why doesn't the event-listener registered to listen to `removeFeature` get executed?

```js
deleteSelectedGeometry() {
    if (this.#featureRecentlyHovered != null) {
        this.#vectorSource.removeFeature(this.#featureRecentlyHovered);
    }
}

#evtListener = (evt) => {
    if (this.#featureRecentlyHovered != null) {
        this.#initWatcherOnDeleteGeometry.value = useWatchedVarUpdat();
    } 
}

registerOnRemoveFeatureFromVectorSource() {
    this.#keyOnRemoveFeature = this.#vectorSource.once('removefeature', (evt) => this.#evtListener(evt));
}
```

Comment: For me it works perfectly OK. It must be problem of where/when you are registering `removefeature` event.